# Register, login, logout Website with Node

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

I'm currently moving on with reading about node. I'm getting through the tutorials well using the command line. However I am thinking ahead and I want to create a simple register, log in and log out website.

Where would I place the node files on a server (all examples I see run from local host:3000)?

What is the best tutorial for creating this type of website from scratch with node?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter where you put the files on the server. The localhost:3000 bit comes from the fact that your core server file tells the server to listen on that port.

I would recommend using the express-generator from npm. It's pretty versatile and does a lot of the leg work.

Just run the following:

```
 npm install express-generator
```

After installing, you'll need to just run the following to create a new web app:

```
 express
```

The details are here: http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html.
Also, try to read through and understand all of the pre-provided code.